# How to get the Date from a DialogFragment back to the container activity?

Tags: android, interface

I have an activity which open a `DialogFragment` that contains a `DatePicker`. How do i get the Selected date back to my activity and how it in a `TextView`? I checked the examples on Android documentation but they are not clear at all. I'm new to programming. All the tutorials I found on shows only how to show the date in a toast within the `DialogFragment`.

Here is my DialogFrament Code

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

DatePickerFragmentListener datePickerListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    //this makes current date as the default date of the calander
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public interface DatePickerFragmentListener {
     void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day ){

    // what do i put here?
}
}
```

and what do i put inside the onDateSet method on my activity?

```
public class FilterGuideList extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.DatePickerFragmentListener {

private LinearLayout from_date;
private LinearLayout to_date;
private TextView from_text;
private TextView to_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter_guide_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //initializing linearlayouts for date picker clickevent
    from_date = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.from_date_selector);
    to_date = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.to_date_selector);

    from_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.from_date_text);
    to_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.to_date_text);


    from_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });

    to_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

      // what do i put here?

}
}
```

I have been trying to get this to work for 2 days now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: look into using interfaces

Comment: Inside oncreatedialog() create Dialog type variable and set onclicklistener to it.

Comment: I'd recommend [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for any kind of sending data between anything :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker
Use above library for datePicker.

[image]

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
}
```

**Implement an OnDateSetListener**

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
  String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year;
  dateTextView.setText(date);
}
```

**Create a DatePickerDialog using the supplied factory**

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
  MainActivity.this,
  now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
  now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

for demo and details visit [here](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

 DatePickerFragmentListener datePickerListener;

 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

//this makes current date as the default date of the calander
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

 public interface DatePickerFragmentListener {
 void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day ){
 datePickerListener.onDataSet(view,year,month,day)

 }
```

**your activity**

```
   public class FilterGuideList extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.DatePickerFragmentListener {

   private LinearLayout from_date;
   private LinearLayout to_date;
   private TextView from_text;
   private TextView to_text;

   ...
   ....
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

   //now you will get value of view,year,month and day here , you can put log here

   }
```